# Scoped roles using mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, cancan

Using Mongoid, if I have an Account model and want to assign Users with specific roles to that account, is it best to embed the relationship within the Account, User or create a roles collection mapping account to user with the role name?

I want to be able to return all users of an account as well as validate that the current user has access to the account with something like Cancan.

What is the recommended way to structure an Account <-> User role based relationship? A user could belong to multiple accounts potentially with different roles, similar to how Basecamp works.

Answer (score 6):

I have recently implemented exactly this. Although a bit more complicated.

What I did was embed the roles in the user

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :roles
end

class Role
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :kind, :type => Symbol
  field :account_id, :type => BSON::ObjectId
  embedded_in :users, :inverse_of => :roles
end

class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
end

#adding a role to user
account = Account.create
user = User.create
user.roles.create(:kind => :admin, :account_id => account.id)

#all users of an account
User.where("roles.account_id" => account.id)

#users accounts
Account.where(:_id => user.roles.map(&:account_id))

#in cancan ability
can :access, Account, :_id => user.roles.map(&:account_id)
```

I also had the cancan query accessible_by working but it required some mods to mongoid to get it to work.

Hope that helps
(Note: I just wrote this code in here so not sure if it runs)